# Tempo REST API (v4) (Jira plugin). How to get a member's email

Tags: python, jira

I'm using the [Tempo REST API](https://apidocs.tempo.io/). Tempo is a plugin for jira. I need to get the member's email, but I'm stuck. Tempo doesn't allow me to do this, I can only get a URL on jira where there is some information about the participant and I can't see the email (it allows only admin users)

Below settings tempo api client

```
import os

from dotenv import load_dotenv
from tempoapiclient import client_v4


load_dotenv()

BASE_URL_TEMPO = 'https://api.tempo.io/4'
AUTH_TOKEN = os.environ.get('AUTH_TOKEN')
HEADERS_TEMPO = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + AUTH_TOKEN}

tempo_client = client_v4.Tempo(auth_token=AUTH_TOKEN)
```

Answer (score -1):

Tempo has several modules, so there are several REST APIs that are available: https://www.tempo.io/server-api-documentation. You can use "TEMPO ACCOUNTS" or "Tempo teams" o get keys of users by and then use Jira core REST API to get email of user by key: https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/9.5.0/#api/2/user-getUser
E.g.: "http://www.example.com/jira/rest/api/2/user?username={USER_KEY}"